# VBA Excel copy name from cell to the left

Tags: excel, vba

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I made some code, that needs to copy the name from the cell to the left, whenever this cell is blank.

The problem is that i only want the code to be ran on row 1.
When i execute the code it loops through my whole worksheet.

How can i modify it, so it only performs the action for row 1.

```
Sub Test()

Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim WS As ActiveSheet

With WS
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

    For i = 2 To LastCol
            If WS.Cells(1, i) = Empty Then
                 WS.Cells(1, i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code will copy text from cell to the left if any cell in the first row is empty till the last column.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to your data sheet

    With WS
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To LastCol
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, i)) Then
                .Cells(1, i).Value = .Cells(1, i).Offset(0, -1).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the code look nice and works like a charm. I already wanted to update my code with the 'set WS' but you already found it. Thnx a lot!